# Who am I?‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏

Tags: wordplay

He was the leader of his people, marching them out of slavery.

He is considered a prophet for all three of the Abrahamic religions.

He is said to have brought to us the Law from God.

**Who am I?**

Comment: I do not understand how this is lateral-thinking tho :)

Comment: It doesn't really matter who **he** is, because the question is: _Who am I?_ :p

Comment: @Wu33o: That is exactly why this question is tagged lateral thinking. Is there perhaps a more appropriate tag?

Comment: There is a [discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/can-we-have-a-garbage-collector-tag) on the meta about this topic ("trick questions", such as these)

Comment: @Wu33o: Thank you. This question was obviously mis-tagged (by me). I'll review the extant tags and decide on a better one. I suppose that lesson was worth a dozen moderation points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it'd be disappointing if the answer was :

> dotancohen

Since

> The question beeing who am I is.. well.. you...

Or

> If i take the question even more literally, the answer is Me.

Comment: Exactly! The trick was to describe somebody obvious, then ask an unrelated question. You got it!

Comment: It is something we saw in the past, that might explain why you got downvoted :) Still funny imo

Answer (score 2):

The figure portrayed  in the riddle is

> Moses

He was the leader of his people, marching them out of slavery.

> Lead Hebrews out of Egypt

He is considered a prophet for all three of the Abrahamic religions.

> Yep...he is mentioned in Judaism, Christianity and Islam

He is said to have brought to us the Law from God.

> He brought down the 10 commandments from the Mount Sinai.

To answer the question "Who Am I?"

> You are a regular religious person. the **us** in 'He is said to have brought to us the Law from God.' could mean that.

Comment: I hope this is not the answer because if so this is not a puzzle at all

Comment: I hope so too :)

Comment: Clearly it's George Clooney

Comment: @Decypher. Can't be, because I'm George Clooney.

Comment: @Marius darnit, thought I nailed it.